# If condition for "not equal" is not working as expected in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash
a=2
b=2
COUNTER=0
sam="abcd"
sam1="xyz"
sam2="mno"
for x in ls | grep .rpm
do
  `C=rpm -qpR $x | grep -v CompressedFileNames | grep -v PayloadFilesHavePrefix | wc -l`

  if [ "sam2"!="$sam1" ]
  then
    echo "${sam1}"
    echo "${sam2}"
    if [ $C -eq $a ]
    then
      COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
      echo "${x}"
      eval sam=$x
      #eval sam1=sam | cut -d '-' -f 1
      sam1=`echo "${sam}"| cut -d '-' -f 1`

      if [ $COUNTER -eq $b ]
      then
        break
      fi
    fi
  fi
  sam2=`echo "${x}"| cut -d '-' -f 1`
done
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
xyz
mno
comps-4ES-0.20050107.x86_64.rpm
comps
comps
comps-4ES-0.20050525.x86_64.rpm
```

My question is: why is the `if` condition returning true despite sam1 and sam2 being equal? I have checked for non-equality.

Response is the same even if I use

```
if [ $C -eq $a ] && [ "$sam2" != " $sam1" ]
```

Comment: `"sam2"!="$sam1"` -> `"$sam2"!="$sam1"`; \`C=...\` -> ``C=`...` ``

Comment: Check this using http://shellcheck.net, and with the `C=` inside backticks, the assignment will happen inside that subshell, so won't be present in the parent

Comment: Really? `for x in ls | grep .rpm`? What's wrong with `for x in *.rpm` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Guys Got the solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "enter dep number" a
read -p "enter no of rpms" b
COUNTER=0
sam="abcd"
sam1="xyz"
sam2="mno"
for x in `ls | grep .rpm`
do

C=`rpm -qpR $x |grep -v CompressedFileNames |  grep -v PayloadFilesHavePrefix | wc -l`
#   echo "${C}:c"
if [ $C -eq $a ]  && [ "$sam2" != "$sam1" ]
then
COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
#   echo "${COUNTER}:counter"
#  echo "${x}"
eval sam=$x
#eval sam1=sam | cut -d '-' -f 1
sam1=`echo "${sam}"| cut -d '-' -f 1`
     if [ $COUNTER -eq $b ]
      then
       break
     fi
  fi

 sam2=`echo "${x}"| cut -d '-' -f 1`
 #echo "${sam2}"
 #echo "${sam1}"

 done
```

Answer (score 1):

As Ansgar Wiechers pointed out, you're missing a "$" in front of the sam2 variable. That way, you're comparing the *literal string* "**sam2**" with the *string value* of `$sam1` (which initially is set to "**xyz**"). What you want to do is compare the string values of both variables:

```
if [ "$sam2" != "$sam1" ]
```

---

Regarding `$C`, you should only include the commands to be evaluated inside backticks, not the evaluation itself. This is called a [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html%20*GNU%20bash%20manual*) - a subshell is created in which the commands are executed, and the backtick expression is substituted by the computed value. The line should look like this:

```
C=`rpm -qpR $x | grep -v CompressedFileNames | grep -v PayloadFilesHavePrefix | wc -l`
```

---

Your `for` loop also needs a command substitution: `for x in ls | grep .rpm` makes it look as if you're piping the output of a for command into grep. What you want to do is iterate over the `ls | grep` part, which you can do with the following command substitution:

```
for x in `ls | grep .rpm`
```

Comment: [You don't want to iterate over `ls` output at all](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). You want to iterate over a [filename pattern expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion):  `for x in *.rpm`